# What is the easiest way to cut ~1000 steel rods - each one 1.5mm in diameter and 12" long - into ~6000 rods that are each 1.75" long?

Tags: materials, steel, machining, cutting

Any ideas for tools and/or jigs that would be best to use for this?

Comment: Check out robotic machines.

Comment: shears of some type

Comment: this is essentially cutting a wire to length. there should be automated machines for that.

Comment: There are tools like the Xuron 2193F that can do that. However it's manual powered and for thousands of cuts you want a pneumatic version.

Comment: Bond all 1000 wires together with wax into a 40x25 rectangle. Wrap masking tape around them at the centre point of each 1.75 length. Use a cutoff saw, preferably a makita ceramic disk to cut 1.75 lengths. Undo the masking tape of the short bundles of sticks, drop each bundle into boiling water. The wax floats free, and you are left with 6000 rods 1.75 long.

Answer (score 1):

#### The easiest way is the way you can do it with the equipment you have.

Every machine shop I've been part of has a [horizontal band saw](https://www.google.com/search?q=horizontal%20band%20saw&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS1043US1043&sxsrf=APwXEdeyEKONUm8Bcuv7p-PppjpK3-jjFQ%3A1685546750559&ei=_mZ3ZIa_Ice7qtsPltq5sAk&ved=0ahUKEwiGtsb67p__AhXHnWoFHRZtDpYQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=horizontal%20band%20saw&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzINCAAQgAQQFBCHAhCxAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzoGCAAQBxAeOgcIABANEIAEOggIABAHEB4QCjoQCAAQDRCABBCxAxCxAxCDAToKCAAQgAQQsQMQCjoHCAAQgAQQCkoECEEYAFCUCli6GGCjGmgCcAF4AIABiQGIAZIKkgEEMC4xMZgBAKABAcABAcgBCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp).  These saws have adjustable stops that can be used to repeat cut lengths.  Depending on the exact holder setup you could cut (and probably would want to) several rods at a time.  We will need a way to hold the rods as they are cut.  This wouldn't be particularly fast, but you didn't specify a work rate.

A human with a ruler, a vise, and a hack saw or shears could do this eventually.

Certainly we could design a machine that could do this, probably with a shearing cutter.  Machines that turn steel coils into straight lengths of steel do this.  I doubt an off-the-shelf machine is available to turn already cut steel into smaller cuts since if you were doing this for  a living you'd make the small cut the first time.

Answer (score 0):

if the material is mild steel, use a shear.